# Get value from the dropdown menu and display desirable html not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
    Look Up Temperature By: 
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="city" selected="selected">City</option>
      <option value="coordinates">Coordinates</option>
      <option value="zip">Zip</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var menu = document.getElementById("dropdown");
        var selected = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].text;
    </script>   

    <script>
        if(selected == "Zip"){
            document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = visible;
            document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = hidden;
            document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = hidden;
        }
        if(selected == "City"){
            document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = hidden;
            document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = visible;
            document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = hidden;
        }
        if(selected == "Coordinates"){
            document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = hidden;
            document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = hidden;
            document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = visible;
        }
    </script>

    <form method="POST" action="/temperature" style="visibility:hidden;" id="zip" position="absolute">
                Enter Your Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zip">
                <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="/temperature" style="visibility:hidden;"  id="city" position="absolute">
                Enter Your City: <input type="text" name="city">
                <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="/temperature" style="visibility:hidden;"  id="coordinates" position="absolute">
                Enter Your Coordinates Values: <input type="texdt" name="coordinates" id="coordinates">
                <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

so what I am trying to do is simply get value from the dropdown menu and display desirable html forms according to the value.

1. It seems like the entire javascript chucks are not working. I printed out "selected" variable, but it is not returning any value
2. Is there efficient way to do "set this one visible but everything else hidden"?

Comment: Code runs once, it does not magically run again when you make a selection. You need to use an onchange event.

Comment: I suggest to you that instead of setting the state for every case, it's better to hide all the forms, and then show the form that you really want to show.

Comment: I suggest you edit your title to something a little more useful. It's very unlikely that someone Googling "HTML javascript not working" is experiencing the same problem you are.

Answer (score 3):

The problem come from `visible/hidden` passed as variables instead of strings :

```
if(selected == "Zip"){
  document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Instead of :

```
if(selected == "Zip"){
    document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = visible;
    document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = hidden;
    document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = hidden;
}
```

You could see the error message in your console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: hidden is not defined

Also you've to wrap your code inside a change event that will be called everytime the user change options in your select list :

```
menu.addEventListener("change", function() {
   //You conditions here
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("dropdown");

menu.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var selected = menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].text;
  
  if(selected == "Zip"){
    document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  if(selected == "City"){
    document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  if(selected == "Coordinates"){
    document.getElementById("zip").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("city").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("coordinates").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
})
```

```html
Look Up Temperature By: 
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="city" selected="selected">City</option>
  <option value="coordinates">Coordinates</option>
  <option value="zip">Zip</option>
</select>

<form method="POST" action="/temperature" style="visibility:hidden;" id="zip" position="absolute">
  Enter Your Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zip">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form method="POST" action="/temperature" style="visibility:hidden;"  id="city" position="absolute">
  Enter Your City: <input type="text" name="city">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form method="POST" action="/temperature" style="visibility:hidden;"  id="coordinates" position="absolute">
  Enter Your Coordinates Values: <input type="texdt" name="coordinates" id="coordinates">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is indeed part of the problem, but the larger issue is that unless the code is wrapped in an event handler it's never really going to work.